# my raspberry pi freezes while face tracking using openCV and servoblaster

Tags: python, opencv, servo

I'm trying to track face with Pan and tilt motion, using servoblaster and opencv, i followed [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Pan-Tilt-face-tracking-with-the-raspberry-pi/?ALLSTEPS) tutorial if anyone is intrested..

it runs perfectly but after few seconds camera freezes and it stops responding and freezes completely. can any one help ? here is the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
import cv2

# Upper limit
_Servo1UL = 250
_Servo0UL = 230

# Lower Limit
_Servo1LL = 75
_Servo0LL = 70


ServoBlaster = open('/dev/servoblaster', 'w')
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 320)     
webcam.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 240)    

frontalface = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml")     
profileface = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_profileface.xml")      

face = [0,0,0,0]    
Cface = [0,0]       
lastface = 0        

Servo0CP = Queue()  
Servo1CP = Queue()  
Servo0DP = Queue()  
Servo1DP = Queue()
Servo0S = Queue()
Servo1S = Queue()

def P0():   
    speed = .1      
    _Servo0CP = 99      
    _Servo0DP = 100
    while True:
        time.sleep(speed)
        if Servo0CP.empty():            
            Servo0CP.put(_Servo0CP)
        if not Servo0DP.empty():
            _Servo0DP = Servo0DP.get()
        if not Servo0S.empty():
            _Servo0S = Servo0S.get()
            speed = .1 / _Servo0S
        if _Servo0CP < _Servo0DP:
            _Servo0CP += 1
            Servo0CP.put(_Servo0CP)
            ServoBlaster.write('0=' + str(_Servo0CP) + '\n')    #
            ServoBlaster.flush()                    #
            if not Servo0CP.empty():
                trash = Servo0CP.get()
        if _Servo0CP > _Servo0DP:
            _Servo0CP -= 1
            Servo0CP.put(_Servo0CP)
            ServoBlaster.write('0=' + str(_Servo0CP) + '\n')    #
            ServoBlaster.flush()                    #
            if not Servo0CP.empty():
                trash = Servo0CP.get()

        if _Servo0CP == _Servo0DP:
            _Servo0S = 1


def P1():   
    speed = .1
    _Servo1CP = 99
    _Servo1DP = 100
    while True:
        time.sleep(speed)
        if Servo1CP.empty():
            Servo1CP.put(_Servo1CP)
        if not Servo1DP.empty():
            _Servo1DP = Servo1DP.get()
        if not Servo1S.empty():
            _Servo1S = Servo1S.get()
            speed = .1 / _Servo1S
        if _Servo1CP < _Servo1DP:
            _Servo1CP += 1
            Servo1CP.put(_Servo1CP)
            ServoBlaster.write('1=' + str(_Servo1CP) + '\n')
            ServoBlaster.flush()
            if not Servo1CP.empty():
                trash = Servo1CP.get()
        if _Servo1CP > _Servo1DP:
            _Servo1CP -= 1
            Servo1CP.put(_Servo1CP)
            ServoBlaster.write('1=' + str(_Servo1CP) + '\n')
            ServoBlaster.flush()
            if not Servo1CP.empty():
                trash = Servo1CP.get()
        if _Servo1CP == _Servo1DP:
            _Servo1S = 1



Process(target=P0, args=()).start() #
Process(target=P1, args=()).start() #
time.sleep(1)               

#====================================================================================================

def CamRight( distance, speed ):        .
    global _Servo0CP
    if not Servo0CP.empty():
        _Servo0CP = Servo0CP.get()
    _Servo0DP = _Servo0CP + distance
    if _Servo0DP > _Servo0UL:

        _Servo0DP = _Servo0UL
    Servo0DP.put(_Servo0DP)
    Servo0S.put(speed)
    return;

def CamLeft(distance, speed):
    global _Servo0CP
    if not Servo0CP.empty():
        _Servo0CP = Servo0CP.get()
    _Servo0DP = _Servo0CP - distance
    if _Servo0DP < _Servo0LL:
        _Servo0DP = _Servo0LL
    Servo0DP.put(_Servo0DP)
    Servo0S.put(speed)
    return;


def CamDown(distance, speed):           
    global _Servo1CP
    if not Servo1CP.empty():
        _Servo1CP = Servo1CP.get()
    _Servo1DP = _Servo1CP + distance
    if _Servo1DP > _Servo1UL:
        _Servo1DP = _Servo1UL
    Servo1DP.put(_Servo1DP)
    Servo1S.put(speed)
    return;


def CamUp(distance, speed):         
    global _Servo1CP
    if not Servo1CP.empty():
        _Servo1CP = Servo1CP.get()
    _Servo1DP = _Servo1CP - distance
    if _Servo1DP < _Servo1LL:
        _Servo1DP = _Servo1LL
    Servo1DP.put(_Servo1DP)
    Servo1S.put(speed)
    return;



#============================================================================================================


while True:

    faceFound = False   #

    if not faceFound:
        if lastface == 0 or lastface == 1:
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   
            fface = frontalface.detectMultiScale(aframe,1.3,4,(cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH),(60,60))
            if fface != ():         
                lastface = 1
                for f in fface:

                    faceFound = True
                    face = f

    if not faceFound:
        if lastface == 0 or lastface == 2:  
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]
            pfacer = profileface.detectMultiScale(aframe,1.3,4,(cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH),(80,80))
            if pfacer != ():        
                lastface = 2
                for f in pfacer:
                    faceFound = True
                    face = f

    if not faceFound:               
        if lastface == 0 or lastface == 3:
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]   
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]
            aframe = webcam.read()[1]
            cv2.flip(aframe,1,aframe)   
            pfacel = profileface.detectMultiScale(aframe,1.3,4,(cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_CANNY_PRUNING + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT + cv2.cv.CV_HAAR_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH),(80,80))
            if pfacel != ():
                lastface = 3
                for f in pfacel:
                    faceFound = True
                    face = f

    if not faceFound:       
        lastface = 0
        face = [0,0,0,0]


    x,y,w,h = face
    Cface = [(w/2+x),(h/2+y)]   
    print str(Cface[0]) + "," + str(Cface[1])

    if Cface[0] != 0:       

        if Cface[0] > 180:  
            CamLeft(5,1)
        if Cface[0] > 190:  #
            CamLeft(7,2)    #
        if Cface[0] > 200:  #
            CamLeft(9,3)    #

        if Cface[0] < 140:  
            CamRight(5,1)
        if Cface[0] < 130:
            CamRight(7,2)
        if Cface[0] < 120:
            CamRight(9,3)

        if Cface[1] > 140:  
            CamDown(5,1)
        if Cface[1] > 150:
            CamDown(7,2)
        if Cface[1] > 160:
            CamDown(9,3)

        if Cface[1] < 100:
            CamUp(5,1)
        if Cface[1] < 90:
            CamUp(7,2)
        if Cface[1] < 80:
            CamUp(9,3)
```

Comment: When you say "freezes completely", do you mean just your python application or the entire Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 1):

Face tracking with OpenCV requires a ton of calculations, so plain and simple the Pi cannot keep up with it, assuming you are running at 700MHz. I had this problem and fixed this by overclocking the Pi a bit. I now get around 25fps using the RasPi Cam module, but I am only using tracking/color filtering, not face tracking. I would recommend trying it, but be careful because the GPU and CPU will get pretty warm, so a heatsink on each would be prudent here. Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

If load on system is high (use "top" command to check) and each detectMultiScale() call is taking too much time (10-100 millisecs is ideal. >500 ms is bad. Use clock_gettime to profile the call), try the following:

1) Introduce a small delay in the while loop

2) Tune the face detection parameters. 
Increase reduction factor from 1.3 to 3 or higher.

Since face detection doesn't need high resolutions, increasing it will scale down the image by that factor and then perform the classification.

I've got good results even with factor of 5 when face is close (< 3-4 feet) in front of camera.

3) Why acquire 5 frames in every iteration only to discard the first 4? It's unnecessary load on the USB driver.